# Return JS in Rails response and have it execute without a .js.erb file

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm currently using this in my controller

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :js => alert('example') }
end
```

And this in my application.js

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess( function(event, xhr, settings) {
  if ( settings.url == '/example' ) {
    eval(xhr.responseText)
  } else if ( settings.url.match(/[\/example\/\d]+$/)) {
    eval(xhr.responseText)
    loadComplete()
  } else {
    (etc)
  }
})
```

To return JS in an ajax response and have the browser execute it. I did this to avoid having to write a new .js.erb file to accommodate each possible response.

Is there a better way of doing this? I thought it would be nice to cut down on the number of files, but having to seperate JS responses using regex on the ajaxSuccess settings.url is pretty gross.

Comment: I dont get it. What do you want to do?

Comment: I have a manage sections page which can add and remove sections. The sections are created and deleted just fine, but I want the ajax response to create or remove elements on the manage sections page, without refreshing. I think using jquery's .load() for a partial would be better.

Comment: Note that `eval(xhr.responseText)` opens the opportunity for unwanted actions to be executed given that $(document).ajaxSuccess fires on **all** successful remote links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to do this is to follow convention and just make the js.erb files. They are automatically executed with assumed actions. For example, the response for creating a section in create.js.erb:

```
$('#placeholder-<%= @subsection[:sortlabel] %>').replaceWith("<%= escape_javascript render :partial => 'section_item', :locals => {:section=>@subsection} %>")
```

And the contents of destroy.js.erb:

```
$('li#menu-item-<%= @section.id %>').remove();
```

Hiding these away in the controller responses might be handy for avoiding creation of (yet another) file, but the maintainability of the app would suffer.